# How to make a foreign key is unique in laravel 0ne to one relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I am building a laravel backend API and I want to map user model to business model using laravel one to one relationship the mapping is successful but I don't want duplicate entries (foreign key of user table)  on businesses table

I am trying to you validator method is unique but it seems not to work I get error

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'businesses_user_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `businesses` (`user_id`, `business_name`, `business_type`, `business_about`, `business_serial`, `business_image`, `business_approved`, `account_balance`, `account_total`, `bank_name`, `account_number`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Vickkys schools, School, osksns dsdsnksds, saiaaja, h8einsnaksnai, 0, 0, 0, aisasna, 324354655343, 2020-04-02 12:48:55, 2020-04-02 12:48:55))

user model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Notifications\PasswordResetNotification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use  Notifiable, HasApiTokens;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new PasswordResetNotification($token));
    }

    public function business()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Business');
    }
}
```

business model

> namespace App;
>
> use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; use App\User; class Business
>   extends Model {
>
> ```
> protected $fillable = ['business_name', 'user_id', 'business_type', 'business_about', 'business_serial',
> ```
>
> 'business_image', 'business_approved', 'account_balance',
>   'account_total', 'bank_name', 'account_number'];
>
> ```
> public function user()
> {
>     return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
> }
> ```

businesscontroller@store

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = Auth::id();
    $request->user_id = $id;
    $request->validate([
        'user_id'           => 'unique:businesses',
        'business_name'     => 'required|unique:businesses|max:255|string',
        'business_type'     => 'required|string|max:255',
        'business_about'    => 'required|string',
        'business_serial'   => 'required|string|max:15',
        'business_image'    => 'required|string',
        'business_approved' => 'required|boolean',
        'bank_name'         => 'required|string|max:255',
        'account_number'    => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $user = User::find($id);
    $business = New business;
    $business->user_id = $request->user_id;
    $business->business_name = $request->business_name;
    $business->business_type = $request->business_type;
    $business->business_about = $request->business_about;
    $business->business_serial = $request->business_serial;
    $business->business_image = $request->business_image;
    $business->business_approved = false;
    $business->account_balance = 0;
    $business->account_total = 0;
    $business->bank_name = $request->bank_name;
    $business->account_number = $request->account_number;

    $newbiz = $user->business()->save($business);

    return response(['business' => $newbiz, 'user' => $user]);
}
```

pls help me user can only register one buisenes

Comment: This is the exact behaviour of one to one, if you want duplications of user_id you have to use one to many relationship !

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique)

`'user_id' => 'unique:businesses,user_id',`